# Frequency calculation for 555 astable multivibrator

Tags: 555

I am using the following circuit to provide PWM input to a dimmable LED driver. I need to know how can I calculate frequency and amplitude of the resultant PWM signal.

[image]

Comment: See https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555-circuits-part-1.html   See the last few configurations on that page for the formulas

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using it for PWM the actual frequency is typically not all that important.

The frequency will be about 1.4/(50K * 100nF). Because of the diodes the frequency will be lower at low Vdd. So in this case, about 280Hz. The capacitor charges through one portion of the 50K element and discharges through the other portion. Since 50K >> 1K, and pot element tolerance is typically loose, the 1K resistor (and also the diode drops and wiper resistance are ignored).

The output voltage swing at pin 3 is dependent on the type of 555 (CMOS or bipolar) and the loading. Lightly loaded, for a CMOS type, it will be close to the power supply voltage. You can get other numbers (dependent on loading etc.) from the relevant 555 datasheet.

The average output voltage will be a fraction of the difference between "high" and "low" voltages that is fairly linearly dependent on the pot setting.